# Recursive setInterval() runs continuously

Tags: javascript, recursion, setinterval

I'm trying to run a function every 5 seconds using JavaScript using a recursive setInterval function.

The following code just logs "started" as fast as possible and then crashes the browser. Why is this not running every 5 seconds?

```
function five() {
console.log("five");
setInterval(five(), 5000);
}
five();
```

Comment: Tommy be sure to mark Joseph's answer as accepted!

Comment: setInterval != setTimeout

Comment: Jeffman's comment is the one I'm planning to accept, is that wrong?

Comment: I think `setInterval` is the more appropriate function to be used in your context.

Comment: setInterval is fine, but only call it ONCE, not every time the function iterates. This is what makes Joseph's answer better than some of the others (until they got revised).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't use setInterval this way. Use setTimeout. By calling setInterval, you create a UNIQUE timer every time the function is called. SetTimeout would create one timer that ends, and then creates a new timer.

You should also change the way you reference `five`. `five()` executes the function immediately. Just `five` passes a function reference, so do it as you see below.

```
function five() {
    console.log("five");
    setTimeout(five, 5000);
}
five();
```

Of course, you can always pass the function call as a string to be evaluated:

```
    setTimeout("five()", 5000); // note the quotes
```

But this is generally considered bad practice.

Comment: Interestingly enough I just noticed this, setTimeout is working for me now the right way.

Comment: If you can add an explanation to use five instead of five() I'll accept this

Answer (score 8):

You're *calling* `five` immediately, instead of merely *passing* it in:

```
function five () {
    console.log("five");
}
setInterval(five, 5000);
/*              ^     */
```

Comment: great! Thank you! Simple yet efficient! :)

Answer (score 3):

Change this line:

```
setInterval(five(), 5000);
```

like this:

```
setInterval(five, 5000);
```

But seems like what you really need is:

```
setTimeout(five, 5000);
```

So your code will look like:

```
function five() {
   console.log("five");
   setTimeout(five, 5000);
}
five();
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason of crashing it is that you are calling the function *five*. Instead of that you should pass it as parameter.

```
setInterval(five, 5000);
```

Comment: i use that setInterval in javascript of google form but it doesn't work. Any clue @Krasimir?

Comment: Well, you have to post some code. I don't know how you exactly use `setInterval`.

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42806155/google-form-with-loop-count-down