# Jquery setInterval into for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop, setinterval

I have two array: `pts` and I want to create new `test` array.

Every time I add new object from `pts` to `test` I need to call function that will execute mimicSvg(test,1) function, with array test (from 0 to m)

I write:

```
var test=[{"X":"300","Y":"400"}];
for(var m=1;m<pts.length;m++){
    var q = pts[m].X;
    var e = pts[m].Y;
    test.push({"X":q,"Y":e});
    setInterval(mimicSvg(test,1), 2000);
  }
```

but setInterval dont work, instead that I get execution on all `m` times function at the same time.

How I can solve that problem?

Comment: If you just would have read [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182714/setinterval-callback-only-runs-once

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18687795/recursive-setinterval-runs-continuously

Comment: Are you sure `setInterval` is the method you want to use here? Looks more like a task for `setTimeout`.

Comment: yes I need etTimeout

Answer (score 2):

`setInterval` takes either a reference to a function to run, or an anonymous function. Because you are trying to call another function with parameters you need to wrap that in an anonymous function declaration. Try this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    mimicSvg(test,1)
}, 2000);
```

Comment: As a side note, you could still pass the params to setInterval() method, no needs of the anonymous function: `setInterval(mimicSvg, 2000, test, 1);`

Comment: @A.Wolff I actually didn't realise that signature was included. Every day is a school day :D

Comment: I try my code and work good with setInteral but why this give me all 25 elements at same time, why dont go by step by for loop: var test=[{"X":"300","Y":"400"}];
for(var m=1;m<pts.length;m++){
    var q = pts[m].X;
    var e = pts[m].Y;
    setInterval(mimicSvg, 2000, test, 1);
    test.push({"X":q,"Y":e});
    console.log(test);
    
  } ? I see console.log and every time I have 25 elemnts, idea behind this is to go step by step, object by object..