# While using setInerval window is hanging

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

```js
 .controller('overviewCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $interval) {
        $scope.cardShow = false;
        $scope.infoShow = true;
        $scope.yes1 = false;
        $scope.yes2 = false;
        $scope.status = true;
        $scope.arbitration = true;
        $scope.notAccepted = true;
        $scope.cardShowRegular = false;
        $scope.check1 = false;
        $scope.id = 53;
        $scope.opportunitiesArr = [];
        $scope.opportunity = [];
        $scope.profile = [];
        /*getting opportunities*/

        $scope.oppList = function () {
            $http.get("https://serviceme.blynksystems.com:6443/createContract/fseoppurtunities/" + $scope.id)
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.opportunitiesArr = response.data;
                    console.log("opportunities " + JSON.stringify($scope.opportunitiesArr));
                }, function (response) {
                    console.log("error" + response);
                });
        }

        /*$rootScope.$broadcast("sendOpportunities", $scope.opportunitiesArr);*/
        $scope.oppList();
        /*end of getting opportunities*/
        $scope.contactInfo = function (opport) {
            $scope.opportunity = opport;
            console.log("opportfjdufiu" + JSON.stringify($scope.opportunity));
            console.log("opport " + JSON.stringify(opport));
            /*$scope.customerId = opport.customer_id;*/
            /*$scope.serviceName = opport.service_name;
            $scope.carModel = opport.car_model;*/
            /*$scope.driverEmail = opport.driver_email;*/
            /*$scope.statusOfFse = opport.status_of_fse;*/
            $scope.cardShow = true;
            $scope.cardShowRegular = true;
            $scope.infoShow = false;
            /*posting the acceptance*/
            if (opport.driver_email != null || opport.driver_email != undefined) {
                var data = {
                    "mechanic_id": $scope.id,
                    /*"customer_id": opport.customer_id,*/
                    "driver_email": opport.driver_email,
                    "service_name": opport.service_name,
                    "car_model": opport.car_model,
                    "status": 2,
                    "counter_price_fse": ""
                }
            } else {
                var data = {
                    "mechanic_id": $scope.id,
                    "customer_id": opport.customer_id,
                    /*"driver_email": opport.driver_email,*/
                    "service_name": opport.service_name,
                    "car_model": opport.car_model,
                    "status": 2,
                    "counter_price_fse": ""
                }
            }
            console.log("emergency" + JSON.stringify(data));
            var req = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'https://serviceme.blynksystems.com:6443/createContract/updatewhenfseaccepted',
                data: data
            }
            $http(req).then(function (response) {
                console.log("respose" + JSON.stringify(response.data));
            }, function (response) {
                console.log(response);

            });
            $scope.callFtn = function () {
    setInterval($scope.contactInfo(opport), 3000);
}
$scope.callFtn();
            /*$interval(function () {
    $scope.contactInfo(opport)
}, 3000);*/
            /*posting the acceptance*/

        }
        });
```

I am working on ionic project.I need to check the status every after 5 seconds in the response which is coming from the server.For that I am using setinterval.But while using this method my window is getting strucked.I also have tried setTimeOut eventhough the same problem is repeating.How can I solve this problem.Here is my code:

Comment: DO you see any errors? `$interval` should work too. Looks like something fails

Comment: I have used $interval too.But in contactInfo function iam showing one div tag.That div is displaying after so much time.

Answer (score 0):

You're using setInterval recursively which ultimately causes the window to get stuck. Please see this for an alternate solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18687829/1912288.

Please use `$interval` in Angular, as it looks for scope changes when `$interval` is called and reflects changes in the bindings. This is done by triggering the digest cycle.

Comment: Thank you.With $interval the function  contactInfo is calling but the POST request inside the function is not calling.I came to know this when the consoles inside the function are printing whenever the contactInfo is calling for every 3 seconds except the POST request console in the success block.